# date is outputting a string literal date

Tags: shell-script, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am writing shell scripts and executing them using Window's command line.

I am learning how to write shell scripts...like I am halfway into chapter 1 if that tells you how much of a novice I am.

When I use the `date` command by itself, it will produce the date.

If I use

```
echo -n `"I am testing: " date`
```

it produces:

```
I am testing: date
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want it to produce:

```
I am testing: Sun June 11 11:30:47
```

Suggestions?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

Comment: "_it produces: `I am testing: date`_" - no it doesn't. It produces `I am testing: : command not found`

Comment: I assure you, that is what was on my screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> echo -n `"I am testing: " date`
> ```

Would try to run the `I am testing:`  command with `date` as argument, collect its output and pass that subject to split+glob as extra arguments to `echo`. I'd expect that to get you an error as it's unlikely your system will have a command by that name.

Possibly you want:

```
printf 'I am testing: %s' "$(date)"
```

Where it's the output of `date` (using the modern `$(...)` form of command substitution instead of the `` `...` `` deprecated one) that we collect to pass to `printf` (which should be used in place of `echo`, especially if you need those non-standard options like `-n`).

Or with `bash` whose `printf` can format dates:

```
printf 'I am testing: %(%c)T' -1
```

(`-1` meaning now. In `ksh93`, where that `%(...)T` comes from, you'd use `now` for that instead).

If you didn't intend to omit the line delimiter (which is what `-n` is for in some `echo` implementations), you could use:

```
date '+I am testing: %c'
```

Where we tell `date` in which format we want the date to be output.

Replace `%c` with `%a %B %d %T` above to get the `Sun June 11 11:30:47` format you show in your question.

Comment: I wonder if the command they actually had was `echo -n "I am testing: " date`, and just the formatting backticks were in the wrong position in the original version of the post. That would match the output `I am testing: date`. If it had been real backticks in the command, they'd have gotten an error.